# Accuracy Measurement in Biased Dataset

Tags: classification, dataset, error

Lets say we have data-set consists of 100 instance, each instance belong to one of 6 classes {1,2,3,4,5,6}. Furthermore, 70% of the instances belong to class 3.

For classification problem, if the output of the classifier is always 3 we will get accuracy of 70%!

Is there a way for measuring accuracy with heavily biased data like the one above?

Comment: You must implicitly have another definition of accuracy in mind. You'll need toa articulate what that is to have an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I did'nt get your point. My definition of accuracy here is Hit or Miss, so if correct we get 1 otherwise we get 0. Do you suggest different definitions?. Is there a way to link accuracy measurement with the distribution of the data?